# is it possible to run external js script in a angularjs/ionic mobile application

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

is it possible to run downloaded external javascript scripts in a angularjs/ionic mobile application? Specially on non jailbreaked iOS devices?

We are thinking about to build a launcher version of my app which downloads the necessary scripts for the app and than installs and runs them. I tried to google around but couldn't find anything on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set a content security policy in your html file which says what external sources your app can access.

Include this in your `<head>` block, adding in your external source server that will host the javascript:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self';
script-src 'self' yoursource.com ">
```